# Copper sulphate use as mould deterrent in evaporative humidifier

Tags: biochemistry

Is it okay to use copper sulphate in an evaporative humidifier to prevent mould growth?

Comment: Maybe you can add more detail regarding how and where exactly you intend to use the copper sulfate.

Comment: Check out for instance: http://npic.orst.edu/factsheets/cuso4gen.html